# Can't open file in php if one of directories is a symlink

Tags: php, path, symlink

I have 3 sites live, staging and development, devel site have copy of all files from live and database copy but staging is not since they are both on the same physical server (staging and devlopment) I want to synlink files from dev to live (it's 30GB) but my php script can't open files where one directory in path is symlink.

I have symlink

`/srv/www/staging.server.com/htdocs/people/ to /srv/www/dev.server.com/htdocs/people/`

and I have example file `/srv/www/dev.server.com/htdocs/people/gnokii/zuluwarrior.svg` I can access it (by `/srv/www/staging.server.com/htdocs/people/zuluwarrior.svg`) from comman line and from the browser but php can't open that file.

`file_exists` return false and `file` return empty array. (I have code that convert svg to png  that work on both live and dev server but don't on staging because of this).

Is there some php config that disble synlinks? I found `suhosin.executor.allow_symlink = Off` but I think it's for executing scripts. Any ideas, how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: @Dow on dev server is't ok, it's the same file, the same server and the same php, file have only one permission.

Comment: Does your webserver have Options FollowSymLinks on?

Comment: Yes, but it's should not matter it's php, and I can open file in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason base_dir was set to '/srv/www/staging.server.com' and `suhosin.executor.allow_symlink` was set to Off

> This flag reactivates symlink() when open_basedir is used, which is
>   disabled by default in Suhosin >= 0.9.6. Allowing symlink() while
>   open_basedir is used is actually a security risk.

Comment: Accept your own answer then ;)

Comment: @F.Orvalho Yes, you can't do this immediately, you need to wait few hours.

Comment: I just try to accept and yout need to wait 2 days to accept your own answer.

Comment: Even if you don't have suhosin, enabled `open_basedir` will have that effect on symlinks. To make it work one would add the linked directory to the list of allowed by open_basedir.